# Average of a Database in Android

Tags: android, sql, database, average

I'm making a school app where you can put the name and the mark of your exams and it will store the marks in a database of three colums ( id, name of exam and mark). I want to make the average of all the exams that I have entered. How can I get the average of the column marks?? (the column of the marks is the lname column)

I attach the adapter class and the open helper class:

```
public class RegistrationOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "REGISTRATION_DB";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "REGISTRATION_TABLE";
public static final int VERSION = 1;
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String FNAME = "F_NAME";
public static final String LNAME = "L_NAME";
public static final String SCRIPT = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
        + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + FNAME
        + " text not null, " + LNAME + " text not null );";

public RegistrationOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(SCRIPT);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("drop table " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

and this is the adapter class:

```
public class RegistrationAdapter {
SQLiteDatabase database_ob;
RegistrationOpenHelper openHelper_ob;
Context context;

public RegistrationAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public RegistrationAdapter opnToRead() {
    openHelper_ob = new RegistrationOpenHelper(context,
            openHelper_ob.DATABASE_NAME, null, openHelper_ob.VERSION);
    database_ob = openHelper_ob.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public RegistrationAdapter opnToWrite() {
    openHelper_ob = new RegistrationOpenHelper(context,
            openHelper_ob.DATABASE_NAME, null, openHelper_ob.VERSION);
    database_ob = openHelper_ob.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void Close() {
    database_ob.close();
}

public long insertDetails(String fname, String lname) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.FNAME, fname);
    contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.LNAME, lname);
    opnToWrite();
    long val = database_ob.insert(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, null,
            contentValues);
    Close();
    return val;

}

public Cursor queryName() {
    String[] cols = { openHelper_ob.KEY_ID, openHelper_ob.FNAME,
            openHelper_ob.LNAME };
    opnToWrite();
    Cursor c = database_ob.query(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, cols, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    return c;

}

public Cursor queryAll(int nameId) {
    String[] cols = { openHelper_ob.KEY_ID, openHelper_ob.FNAME,
            openHelper_ob.LNAME };
    opnToWrite();
    Cursor c = database_ob.query(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, cols,
            openHelper_ob.KEY_ID + "=" + nameId, null, null, null, null);

    return c;

}

public long updateldetail(int rowId, String fname, String lname) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.FNAME, fname);
    contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.LNAME, lname);
    opnToWrite();
    long val = database_ob.update(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, contentValues,
            openHelper_ob.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
    Close();
    return val;
}

public int deletOneRecord(int rowId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    opnToWrite();
    int val = database_ob.delete(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME,
            openHelper_ob.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
    Close();
    return val;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

your sql query for taking avrage of a column is

```
public int get_Avg(){


String query= "SELECT AVG(lname) From Your_Table_name";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
//Add in the movetofirst etc here? 
c.moveToFirst(); 
int AverageValue=c.getInt(0);
Log.e("","Your average value is : "+AvrageValue);


 return AverageValue;
}
```

and then in your activity call that function

```
  RegistrationAdapter  adapter=new RegistrationAdapter (Your_Activity_Name.this);
```

and then

```
your_TextView.setText("Avrage is : "+adapter.get_Avg());
```

Comment: And how can I display the average un a textview ?

Comment: Create function that will contain code that i have written in my answer and that function will return a int value and from your activity call that function like check my updated answer.

Comment: I have a problem, when I put curso c = db.rawQuery(query,null)  it says that cannot resolve symbol db, why?

Comment: @Alex Cos you do not have defined db write   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); in your function.

Comment: I have solved the problem of db, but now it seems that all works but when I test the app it doesn't work, when I start the app it close